# Connecting to ftp.gnu.org failed

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-14.04, buildroot

after adding a new package in buildroot/package/

The package contains a Config.in

I added the path in package /Config.in

After that I build the project an I got this error

--2020-03-03 14:16:12--  http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.bz2

Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... 209.51.188.20

Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|209.51.188.20|:80... failed: Connection timed out.

Retrying.

I didn't understand the error

Answer (score 2):

Buildroot failed downloading the source code for a package it needs for the build. The reason is "Connection timed out", meaning the ftp.gnu.org server did not respond or there was a networking failure along the path between your computer and the server.

Check your connectivity by downloading the file from your browser.
You can simply click the URL in your question. This works here,
if it fails it's probably a transient server error, try again later.

Otherwise check that `wget` (the tool that Buildroot uses to download) works as well. From a shell terminal:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.bz2
```

If it fails: does your browser use a proxy to connect to the internet?